# Check if uploaded image is CMYK in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, bitmap, arrays, cmyk

Is there any way to figure this out which user uploaded image in our flex project is RGB or CMYK?

Something like using byteArray and check the specific place of CMYK/RGB header on it...

Comment: what type of image? bmp, jpg, gif, ???? why is it needed?

Comment: JPG! Because our project is kinda photo editor which we want print the results including user photos uploaded. We do not want to accept CMYK ones.

Comment: but if you load it into an image, it gets converted, isnt it?

Comment: Indeed! But I do want to check it before load and upload photo completely. Something like this, but it does not work for all kind of photos: http://www.anttikupila.com/flash/getting-jpg-dimensions-with-as3-without-loading-the-entire-file/